# Is it better to display and review the business information on the review page step or should it be presented in a step after selecting a business?

Tags: usability, users, business

I am trying to design a business contractor licence application process. Before starting the application(the stepper), the user has to select and confirm which business account the licence is for. The business account selection displays the legal name along with the address. Once selected the stepper flow starts and the 1st step is to select the technology that they are applying for. 2nd step is confirming the pre populated business information. 3rd step is to submit the required documents. 4th step user review all the information. 5th is Pay and Submit.

For better user experience, is it better to display and review the business information on the review page step or should it be presented in a step after selecting a business?

I believe displaying and reviewing the business information on the review page step, rather than presenting it in a separate step after selecting a business, would allow users to confirm all their entered information in one place before finalizing their application. This approach avoids the need for users to confirm their information multiple times, streamlining the process and reducing potential confusion. However, I'm uncertain whether this aligns with best practices, and I'd appreciate hearing the opinions and feedback from all the experts here. Images below shows all the current steps.

[image: Select Business]

[image: 2nd Step-Review Business information and update if needed]

[image: 3rd Step-AddRequirements]

[image: 4th Step- Again Review Business Information and other information and edit if necessary]

I understand that conducting user testing or gathering feedback from stakeholders can help determine the most effective approach for my design. However, due to time and budget constraints, we are unable to conduct usability testing at this stage. We will be performing User Acceptance Testing (UAT) once the design is developed. Given these limitations, I am seeking help from this forum as I do not have access to any other resources. Any assistance or guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Is it better to display and review the business information on the review page step, or should it be presented in a step after selecting a business?* -- Which one is the review page step (I assume you mean this), and what step would it be otherwise?

Comment: My question is about the necessity of Step Number 2 in our process. In this step, the all the fields are pre-populated and users can update it if needed. However, since all the information is confirmed in Step Number 4 (Review and edit if necessary), I'm wondering if Step Number 2 is redundant. I believe that displaying and reviewing the business information in the review step only would allow users to confirm everything in one place before finalizing their application, rather than confirming in two separate places. I'd appreciate your thoughts on what would be better. Thank you!@Devin

Answer (score 0):

OK, while it's not necessarily bad, it's a common pattern to have a Review instance at the end. The reason for this is that users are performing actions that require a cognitive load, and the amount of friction in finance and insurance apps is really high (hence why "no review" is used as a dark pattern by fishy companies). Therefore, the chance of incurring errors and mistakes is quite high. On top of that, [writing is one of the tasks that require the most cognitive load.](https://www.kosmotime.com/cognitive-load/)

However, a read-only step where users can review without having to input data lowers that cognitive load and improves the chance for users to detect any mistakes they might have made.

In short, I think having this review page at the end is a common and tested pattern; then again, it's not necessarily the best one. You can test the other option with users to get insights on both user paths.

Comment: Hey Davin, thanks a bunch for chiming in and offering your insights! I really appreciate your help with this. I understand that having a review page at the end is a common practice, and I'll be sure to include it in the Stepper.

However, I'm pondering whether having both Step 2 (Review Business Info Step) and Step 4 (Review all info) might be a bit redundant. 

Do you think it would provide a better user experience to streamline it and just have Step 4 (Review all info) without Step 2? I'd love to hear your thoughts on this!

Comment: but for what I see Step 2 is edition and Step 4 is read-only, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Devin, your assistance means a lot to me. I'm feeling a bit stuck here and unsure about what would provide the best experience for our users. 
To clarify, in Step 2, all the fields are pre-filled since the user has already selected the account for their license application. It's mainly for ensuring that the address and contact info are accurate. Users can edit/update the addresses only at this stage.
I think Step 2 might be a bit redundant or unnecessary since users can review and edit everything on the final review page (Step 4). I'm unsure whether to include Step 2 or not. How do you feel?